# How to use SEO urls in CakePHP without the ID?

Tags: cakephp, seo, routes, url

Is there a simple way to route my URLs without showing the ID in the URL. For example i have:

www.mywebsite.com/id-article-title.html and i want only www.mywebsite.com/article-title.html

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a url column to your db table. Then you can do `findByUrl()`. As noted above it's well documented.

```
function view($url = null) {
    if (!$url) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid url');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->set('something', $this->Something->findByUrl($url));
}
```

You can create `beforeSave` methods to process your urls for uniqueness an uuencoding.

You can eliminate the need to specify `www.domain.com/controller/view/latest-news` using routes like:

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'somethings', 'action' => 'view'))
```

Now `www.domain.com/latest-news` will return the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this one but I think the link below may help you somewhat

**[adding friendly urls to the cake application](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/adding-friendly-urls-to-the-cake-blog-tutorial)**

**[using url slugs in cakephp](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/using_url_slugs_in_a_cakephp_app/)**